# What unity skills and other technologies I need for high paying Unity jobs?

Tags: programming, game-design

I got a low paid unity job with my beginner-intermediate knowledge of unity. Now what unity skills and other technologies I should be learning to get a high paying job that requires experience and a bunch of skillsets related to game dev?
(example: like some high paying job descriptions require backend integration)
It would be great if someone with game dev experience could list it all.

Comment: I fail to see how this question fits into this forum.

Comment: Where else I should post it then? @Kai

Comment: @EradAli this is mostly a forum for computer science educators to ask questions of other computer science educators. To be honest, your question isn't what stack exchange was designed for. SE centers around questions that have a right answer. You might do better on Quora or Reddit. (Though tbh you might want to write a few more sentences about what you think *might* be on that list if you want to be well received in any of those forums.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find 10 job listings for high-paying Unity jobs at companies you would actually work for, in location you would be okay living in (moving to).
Find 10 more job listings with nearly identical role/psotion titles, bit are either far away (even in a different country), or in an industry or company you wouldn't want to work for or in.

Download the text, or otherwise paste it all into Notepad++. Trim the excess. Keep the company descriptions but in a separate file. There are two main areas on any job listing: responsibilities, and qualifications

Your goal is to find the pattern in these. Group them together. Be sure to annotate in some way a responsibility" or qualifications that is a "nice to have" versus a "need to have".

Once you've done this, you will know exactly what to learn, or that you'd better move somewhere else if you ever want to make good money. You can follow up this exercise with looking ad 10 LinkedIn profiles of people in the industry who are either making a lot with Unity, have high-skill, or both.